# Need help with part identification... can't find part number

Tags: part-identification

No apparent part number that I could find. Help with IDing this part? Thank you!

[image] [image]

Comment: First obligatory Q: does the stud have "LEGO" imprinted on it?

Comment: Yup, it does. I have a BrickLink store and list parts all the time, so I know for certain this is lego :) Impossible to tell in the photo though, so I appreciate the question. That aside, I looked inside the part with a flashlight as well, so definitely no part number. Just need someone who knows the name of this piece or what it might be.

Answer (score 9):

Found it while looking for a different part in the inventory! It is [2463 Brick, Modified Facet 3 x 3 x 2 Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2463)

Comment: You may want to mark your answer as the accepted one